# Spring : Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans, crud

I have a problem with Spring and the CrudRepository, my code doesn't compile I have this error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [person.repository.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
... 18 common frames omitted
```

My code :

Application.java

```
package person.application;
        @SpringBootApplication 
    public class Application {

        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public CommandLineRunner demo(PersonRepository repository) {
            return (args) -> {
                // save a couple of customers
                repository.save(new Client(1,"keke","boy","kekeboy","ee","r","","","","",""));
             };
         }

    }
```

PersonRepository.java

```
package person.repository;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Client, Long> {

    List<Client> findBylastname(String lastName);

}
```

Person.java

```
@Entity
public class Client {

}
```

configuration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean class="person.repository.PersonRepository"/>
</beans>
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: If it's spring boot application and you're following the typical spring boot app structure, you won't need the `configuration.xml`. So, drop the configuration

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to @Repository for the interfaces. Remove it and add following

```
<repositories base-package="person.repository" />
```

Take a look at here

[Repositories >>](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot recommends that you locate your main application class in a root package above other classes. The `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation is often placed on your main class, and it implicitly defines a base `search package` for certain items. For example, if you are writing a JPA application, the package of the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotated class will be used to search for `@Entity` or `@Repository` items. So, i recommend you change your project structure to something like following:

```
com
 +- example
     +- myproject
         +- Application.java (annotated with @SpringBootApplication)
         |
         +- model
         |   +- Client.java
         |
         +- repository
         |   +- ClientRepository.java
         |   +- PersonRepository.java
         |
         +- service
         |   +- ClientService.java
         |
```

With this structure, you won't need the `configuration.xml`, so you can safely drop it. Read more on this topic in spring boot [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class). Also make sure that you have the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

where is your implements of PersonRepository? if you have,you should add  annotation to let interface know which it is injection.

error is "expected at least 1 bean"  means they can`t find it~

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"person.repository"})`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html) annotation in your `Application.java` class. This Annotation is used to enable JPA repositories. It Will scan the package of the annotated configuration class for Spring Data repositories by default. You can also specify this using `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=PersonRepository.class)`

   .
2. No need to specify `@Repository` on `PersonRepository` class. `@EnableJpaRepositories`  Annotation in #1 will identify it as a `JPA Repository`.
3. Just remove `configuration.xml`file. It is not required.